# ExpandableListView Multilevel in Kotlin groupsPosition of firstChild always 0

Tags: kotlin, expandablelistview, multi-level

i'm new in Kotlin and learning this Coding-Language right now.
At the moment i get stuck on the Problem that in my Multi-Level expandablelistview in secondlevel the groupPosition is always "0".
The view shows always 3 times the same objects, but it must be 3 different objects.

The Data comes from a local running SQL-Lite Database and the Databasequery works fine.

Here is my code, I hope you can help me!

```java
class pflegeRabGru :AppCompatActivity(){
    val ctx:Context = this
    internal var expandableListView: ExpandableListView?=null
    internal var listAdapter: ExpandableListAdapter?=null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pflege_rabgru)
        expandableListView= findViewById(R.id.expRabListView)

        if (expandableListView !=null){
            listAdapter=adapter_RabGruKat(this)
            expandableListView!!.setAdapter(listAdapter)
        }

    }
```

The First Adapter
adapter_RabGruKat

```java
class adapter_RabGruKat internal constructor(private val context: Context):BaseExpandableListAdapter() {
    val lclDb=lclDBHelper(context)
    val listRabgru = ArrayList<ArtRabGru>()
    val listRabFields = ArrayList<RabGruFields>()
    val listCats = ArrayList<Categorys>()
    val listReadedRabgru= getRabForGroups()
    val listReadedRabKats = getKatsForGroups()


    override fun getChild(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int):Int{
        return childPosition
    }

    override fun getChildId(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Long{
            return childPosition.toLong()
    }

    override fun getChildView(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int, isLastChild: Boolean, convertView: View?, parent:ViewGroup):View{
        var convertView = convertView
        var subObjects = ExpandableListView(context)

        subObjects!!.setAdapter(adapter_RabGruKatChilds(context,childPosition.toLong(),getGroup(groupPosition).get(groupPosition).WAHID))
        subObjects!!.setGroupIndicator(null)

        return subObjects
    }

    override fun getChildrenCount(groupPosition: Int): Int {
        return listCats.size
    }

    override fun getGroup(groupPosition: Int):ArrayList<ArtRabGru>{
        return listRabgru
    }

    override fun getGroupCount(): Int {
        return listRabgru.size
    }

    override fun getGroupId(groupPosition: Int): Long {
        return groupPosition.toLong()
    }

    override fun getGroupView(groupPosition: Int,isExpanded: Boolean, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        var convertView = convertView
        val groupTitle = getGroup(groupPosition).get(groupPosition).WAH_RABGRU + " " + getGroup(groupPosition).get(groupPosition).WAH_RABGRUTEXT
        val groupId = getGroup(groupPosition).get(groupPosition).WAHID

        if (convertView==null){
            val layoutInflater = this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_pflege_rabgru, null)
        }

        val listRabGruTitle = convertView!!.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtRabgruName)
        val listRabId = convertView!!.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtRabGruId)

        listRabGruTitle.text=groupTitle
        listRabId.text=groupId.toString()
        return convertView
    }

    override fun hasStableIds(): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun isChildSelectable(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int):Boolean {
        return true
    }

    fun getRabForGroups():ArrayList<ArtRabGru>{
        lclDb.readAllArtRabGru().forEach() {
            listRabgru.add(ArtRabGru(it.WAHID,it.WAH_RABGRU,it.WAH_RABGRUTEXT))
        }
        return listRabgru
    }

    fun getKatsForGroups():ArrayList<Categorys>{
        lclDb.readAllCategory().forEach {
            listCats.add(Categorys(it.KATID,it.KATNAME))
        }
        return listCats
    }
}
```

and the SecondLevelAdapter

```java
class adapter_RabGruKatChilds internal constructor(private val context:Context, private val childPositionOtherAdapter:Long,private val selectedRabgru:Long) : BaseExpandableListAdapter() {
    val lclDb = lclDBHelper(context)
    var listCats = ArrayList<Categorys>()
    val readCats = getKatsForGroups()
    val rabFields = ArrayList<RabGruFields>()
    val readRabFields = getFieldRabs()

    override fun getChild(childPosition: Int, groupPosition: Int):RabGruFields {
        return rabFields.get(childPosition)
    }

    override fun getChildId(groupPosition:Int, childPosition:Int): Long {
        return childPosition.toLong()
    }

    override fun getChildView(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int, isLastChild: Boolean, convertView: View?, parent:ViewGroup): View {
        var convertView = convertView
        val fieldId= getChild(childPosition,groupPosition).RABFIELDID
        val fieldName= getChild(childPosition,groupPosition).RABFIELDTEXT

        if (convertView==null){
            val layoutInflater = this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
            convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pflegefieldsitems, null)
        }

        val txtfieldId = convertView!!.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtFieldId)
        val txtfieldName = convertView!!.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtFieldName)

        txtfieldId.text=fieldId.toString()
        txtfieldName.text=fieldName
        return convertView
    }

    override fun getChildrenCount(groupPosition: Int): Int {
        return rabFields.size
    }

    override fun getGroup(groupPosition: Int):Categorys{
        Log.i("INFO", "GroupPosition in getGroupt="+ groupPosition.toString())
        return listCats.get(groupPosition)
    }

    override fun getGroupCount(): Int {
        return listCats.size
    }

    override fun getGroupId(groupPosition: Int):Long {
        return groupPosition.toLong()
    }

    override fun getGroupView(groupPosition: Int,isExpanded:Boolean, convertView:View?, parent:ViewGroup): View? {
        var convertView = convertView
        val groupCatId = getGroup(groupPosition).KATID
        val groupTitle = getGroup(groupPosition).KATNAME

        if(convertView==null){
            val layoutInflater = this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_pflege_rabgru, parent,false)
        }
        val txtCatId = convertView!!.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtRabGruId)
        val txtCatName = convertView!!.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtRabgruName)

        txtCatId.text= groupCatId.toString()
        txtCatName.text = groupTitle

        Log.i("INFO", "GroupPosition in getGroupView=" + groupPosition.toString())
        return convertView
    }

    override fun hasStableIds(): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun isChildSelectable(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Boolean {
        return true
    }


    fun getKatsForGroups():ArrayList<Categorys>{
        listCats.clear()
        lclDb.readAllCategory().forEach {
            listCats.add(Categorys(it.KATID,it.KATNAME))
        }
        return listCats
    }

    fun getFieldRabs(): ArrayList<RabGruFields>{
        rabFields.clear()
        lclDb.readAllRabFields(selectedRabgru).forEach{
            rabFields.add(RabGruFields(it.RABID, it.RABGRUID,it.RABFIELDID,it.RABFIELDMANDATORY,it.RABFIELDSHOW,it.RABFIELDTEXT,it.RABFIELDRANDOMIZE))
        }
        return rabFields
    }
}
```